# Using Jenkins and pulling code from SVN

Tags: svn, jenkins, ant, build, compilation

I am new to Jenkins, I am using Jenkins 2.60.2 with SVN & ANT

How do i tell Jenkins to take code from SVN and copy files to some location on windows and Linux system ?

How do i tell Jenkins to take code from SVN and give it to ANT for compile, create jars and deploy it on production system ?

Comment: Have you tried searching for a tutorial. Here's the top result from Google https://eureka.ykyuen.info/2013/10/04/jenkins-setup-a-simple-ant-build-project/

Comment: It is pretty straight forward. When configuring a new job mark the "Poll SCM" checkbox and configure where the sources are on the SVN server.